# Angular $http doesn't send any data

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use angular $http service to send an object, but when I inspect Network tab for request, there is no data attribute (there is request though) which means, data was never submitted.

I've made dozens of application that are API model based and never ever had any problem with sending $http requests.

Best Regards

Here is my code:

```
$scope.getMultipleTimesService = function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                data: {'times': ["1", "2"]},
                dataType: 'json',
                url:  'http://api.domain.com/times'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                defer.resolve(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });

            return defer.promise;
        };
```

Comment: Why are you not using POST instead of GET to send data?

Comment: Simply reading the $http docs would have alerted you to difference between `data` and `params`. When in doubt read the manual

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a request body with the `GET` HTTP method. If you need a body, use `POST`.

However, if you want to pass query params you should use the `params` option to pass data for the query string.

```
$scope.getMultipleTimesService = function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                params: {'times': ["1", "2"]},
                url:  'http://api.domain.com/times'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                defer.resolve(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });

            return defer.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style:

```
$scope.getMultipleTimesService = function(){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('http://ursampleurl.com',{'time': ['t1','t2']} )
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
          })
          .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('some error')
          })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: `success` is deprecated and you should be recommending using preffered promise method per docs